# How to run the same google test case with different google mocks?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

There are several test cases which was using a service. The test cases are written with google test. The service can be of different types, so I have mocked each one with google mock. How do I write the tests in such a way so they can be run with different mocks without writing the same tests again and again with different mocks?

The same test case for 2 different mocks are written like this:

```
// For mock A
TEST_F(MockASampleTest, sample_test_case)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(mockA, mockAFunc(_))
        .Times(1)
        .WillOnce(Return(mockARetVal));
    EXPECT_EQ(testObj.testFunc(), 32);
}

// For mock B
TEST_F(MockBSampleTest, sample_test_case)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(mockB, mockBFunc(_))
        .Times(1)
        .WillOnce(Return(mockBRetVal));
    EXPECT_EQ(testObj.testFunc(), 32);
}
```

So, the problem is that the EXPECT_CALLS are different for different mocks due to different method names and return values of the mocks. How can I combine these 2 test cases into one?

Comment: `MotorcycleMock mc; test1(mc); MinivanMock van; test1(van); SemitruckMock semi; test1(semi);`

Comment: [Typed Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#typed-tests) looks relevant for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GoogleMock framework to create and control mocks during the tests' execution, you can specify (using e.g. `EXPECT_CALLS`) how the mock should behave.

The object under tests shouldn't care about what type of mock is used in given tests if you use Dependency Inversion Principle from SOLID (i.e. there should be no code that depend on mock type in the class under test; the tested class should depend on interface, not concrete implementation)

Comment: Should the EXPECT_CALLS be inside the test case? Then for different mocks, different EXPECT_CALLS statements will be required inside the test case. I guess I can put them under an "if constexpr".

Comment: I see it differently: different `EXPECT_CALL`s make it different test cases. For example, if for the same method one service would return valid ptr but another service can return nullptr, these two should be two different cases. Could you add some code snippets to your question?

Comment: To me these are two different tests and should be separated, as they are now. If you insist on having them somehow combined, there are 2 options: if both mocks are derived from the same base class, make a parametrized test for MockASampleTest where mock and a function with expect call is a parameter (you can achieve it by creating a function in MockASampleTest with proper expect call and pass the address to this member method as parameter to parametrized test). 2nd option if mocks are not related: typed test and again methods in MockASampleTest with mock type as parameter using tag dispatching